# Как отобразить текстуру в OpenGL без замыливания?

Tags: opengl

Есть картинка очень малого разрешения, 16х16 к примеру (увеличена для демонстрации):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Когда я натягиваю ее как текстуру на поверхность, ее ОЧЕНЬ смазывает и она превращается в очень мыльную:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как растянуть картинку, без вот этого вот смазывания?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Используй

```
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST); 
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
```

Флаг `GL_NEAREST` означает что все тексели будут четкими при увеличении (в паре с параметром `GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER`) и при уменьшении (в паре с параметром `GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER`).

Будет вот так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо тебе ОГРОМНОЕ)

Comment: Рад помочь. Если данный ответ тебе помог - поставь плюс. Если решил проблему - отмечай галкой принятым :-)

Answer (score 1):

[MIP-текстурирование](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIP-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5) может помочь вам в этой проблеме
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Mip уровни тут совершенно не при чем. Вопрос об отображении размазанной текстуры при увеличении, а не уменьшении.

Comment: Дак как бы нормально - это делать большую текстуру потом уменьшать... кто в здравом уме квадратики хочет при увеличении кроме автора ? :) Пока он картинки не привел, даже предположить было сложно какой результат ему нужен :)

Comment: @EvgenyKaravashkin: А зачем делать большую текстуру, когда можно оботйтись маленькой и идеально четкой? ;-) Тут все зависит от задачи и авторского стиля. Может быть автор пиксель-арт игру делает. А простейший пример где это нужно в 3D - Minecraft.

Comment: Дак да, можно, но просто автор сначала картиночки то не привел. А по тексту сложно догадаться что ему нужен пиксель арт :) Ну т.е. вообще изначально заглавный пост то был не такой как сейчас.